# Joining several terms into one table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
GENRES
gID | gNAME
1   | Fiction 
2   | Non-Fiction
3   | Comedy
4   | Horror
```

And this table

```
PRODUCTS
pID | pNAME 
1   | 4 hour work week
2   | screw it let's do it
```

And then the assign table:

```
ASSIGNTABLE
aID | pID | gID
1   | 1   | 1
2   | 1   | 2
3   | 2   | 2
4   | 2   | 3
5   | 2   | 4
```

I need a query that will return the following:

```
pID | pNAME                 | pGENRE
1   | 4 hour work week      | Fiction
2   | screw it let's do it  | Non-Fiction
```

In other words, I need to ONLY get ONE genre per product. How do i do this?

Comment: For products with multiple genres, which one do you want to select?

Comment: the first one, please...

Comment: MySQL tables are unordered.  How do you define "first one"?

Comment: Order by KEY. First would be the first one inserted into the database in this case.

Comment: Having a lower `gID` does not *necessarily* mean that the record was inserted before another with a higher `gID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, MySQL tables are unordered.  If by "first one" you mean that you want the genre with the smallest `gID`, you can use a subquery to group the `ASSIGNTABLE` by `pID` and identify the desired genres:

```
SELECT    PRODUCTS.*, GENRES.gNAME
FROM      PRODUCTS
  JOIN  ( SELECT pID, MIN(gID) gID FROM ASSIGNTABLE GROUP BY pID ) t USING (pID)
  JOIN    GENRES USING (gID)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30ae3/1).